# How can I create and combine period intervals?

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to create period interval like this
(0 , 5] month and (5 , 10] month.
And then merge these interval into (0 , 10] month.
I simplified my real problem with the dataframe below.

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(lubridate::period(c(0,1,0),c("day","month","year")), 
lubridate::period(c(0,2,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,3,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,4,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,5,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,6,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,7,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,8,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,9,0),c("day","month","year")),
lubridate::period(c(0,10,0),c("day","month","year"))
))


cut(df$age,breaks = c(
  lubridate::period(c(0,0,0),c("day","month","year")),
  lubridate::period(c(0,5,0),c("day","month","year")),
  lubridate::period(c(0,10,0),c("day","month","year"))
))
```

cut function return  intevals

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the underlying numeric format.

```
breaks <- c(
  lubridate::period(c(0,0,0),c("day","month","year")),
  lubridate::period(c(0,5,0),c("day","month","year")),
  lubridate::period(c(0,10,0),c("day","month","year"))
)
cut(as.numeric(df$age), as.numeric(breaks), labels=as.character(breaks)[-1])
# [1] 5m 0d 0H 0M 0S  5m 0d 0H 0M 0S  5m 0d 0H 0M 0S  5m 0d 0H 0M 0S 
# [5] 5m 0d 0H 0M 0S  10m 0d 0H 0M 0S 10m 0d 0H 0M 0S 10m 0d 0H 0M 0S
# [9] 10m 0d 0H 0M 0S 10m 0d 0H 0M 0S
# Levels: 5m 0d 0H 0M 0S 10m 0d 0H 0M 0S
```